# Android ListView height to match_parent minus fixed height

Tags: listview, kotlin, height

I have a LinearLayout that has a listview in it, and at the bottom I have a realativeLayout that has 3 buttons in it.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listdogs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:visibility="visible">


    </ListView>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dogmap"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
            android:background="@drawable/map" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dogphone"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/phone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dogaweb"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
            android:background="@drawable/website" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to have the listview set like: android:layout_height="match_parent" but I want it to substract -80dp from that height so it allows my relativeLayout at the bottom to be shown.

I thought that if I added  android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" it would give me the space needed to show my relativeLayout, but it didn´t happen. It only added a blank space there and move my buttons out of the screen.

thank you in advance 4 your support

Regards

Comment: Let me know if my answer is what you were looking for! :)

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I was looking for!!! tyvm Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the weight of the `ListView` you can achieve the result you want:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listdogs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible">


</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dogmap"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:background="@drawable/map" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dogphone"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/phone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dogaweb"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/website" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

as you can see I added `android:layout_weight="1"` to the `ListView` and that will push it till the `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest always use **ConstraintLayout**, here it is how it will look like in **ConstraintLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:visibility="visible"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listdogs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="bottom_bar"
      android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
      android:focusable="true"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
      android:textSize="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
      android:visibility="visible">


  </ListView>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/listdogs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="80dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dogmap"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:background="@drawable/map"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dogphone"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/phone"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dogaweb"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/website"/>
  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Summary of changes:***

1. Changed root from relative ConstraintLayout
2. added layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf for list view
3. added layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf for bottom bar

Answer (score 0):

My choice is a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <ListView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/rl"
        android:id="@+id/listdogs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:visibility="visible">
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dogmap"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
            android:background="@drawable/map" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dogphone"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/phone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dogaweb"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
            android:background="@drawable/website" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```